# Leading zeros using implode to download csv Laravel 4

Tags: php, csv, laravel

When I download the csv:

54 is displayed instead of 00054. I'm using the next code:

```
    $table = PldUsuario::all();
    $output='';
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        $output.=  implode(",",$row->toArray());
        $output.= "\n";
    }
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="UsersPld.csv"',
    );
    return Response::make(rtrim($output, "\n"), 200, $headers);
```

In my table in mysql displayed 00054.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the program you're using to display the CSV (e.g. Excel) turning 00054 into 54 for display?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php PS: "54 is displayed instead of 00054" --- displayed by *what*?

Comment: then put " " around $output.

Comment: Just a note, simply putting " " around the field really only tells excel to ignore commas within the quotes.  You have to put an equal sign in front of the quotes to tell excel to display it exactly as it is written (as a string instead of auto-formatting the cell).

Comment: Yes I had to put an equal sign. Thank's James

Comment: @James : kindly pls advice me on my questions as well.. pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478936/laravel-csv-how-to-get-csv-file-with-front-zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get excel to not remove the leading zeros, first make sure that they are a string in your initial array, then when setting them as the field in the CSV, it should read `,="00054"`.  You'd probably need to go through your `$row->toArray()` prior to imploding it to make those fields be `"=\"00054\""` first.