# laravel csv , how to get csv file with front zeros

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5.1

when I generate my csv file , some of the special charactors and front zero of cell values are not getting . pls advice how to fix this

```
    public function csv()
    {
        // $table = Festivals::all();
        $headers = [
            'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
            , 'Content-type' => 'text/csv'
            , 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=sss.csv'
            , 'Expires' => '0'
            , 'Pragma' => 'public'
        ];

              $list = Festivals::select('ref_no','artist_name','postal_address','payment','payment_fee','bank_details','bank_name','bank_address','account_name','account_number','sort_code','reg_vat','vat_reg_number'
,'foreign_artise','name_desg','email','mobile','name_address','vehicle_size','backline','additional_backline','name','date')->get()->toArray();


        # add headers for each column in the CSV download
        array_unshift($list, array_keys($list[0]));

        $callback = function () use ($list) {
            $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            foreach ($list as $row) {
                fputcsv($FH, $row);
            }
            fclose($FH);
        };

        return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
    }
```

EDIT
[image]

Comment: You are probably reading the values as integers, but to keep the left zeros you have to read them as strings.

Comment: @Laerte : how can I do this? I stored all values as VARCHAR

Comment: To be honest I don't know how your code works, but I had the same problem importing from JSON. To solve the problem I've changed my database column from integer to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tharu,

Well I'm not sure what your data looks like at this point: `fputcsv($FH, $row);`

However, I'll make a few assumptions and we can go from there.

First, it's possible that your zeros are already missing within the `$row` array.  But for now, please add this above `fputcsv($FH, $row);`:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    $row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val).'"';
}
```

See how much that does for you.  If it's still not working right, please show me a line of the current output, and let me know what is wrong with it.

**EDIT**

I mean to do this:

```
$callback = function () use ($list) {
    $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val).'"';
        }
        fputcsv($FH, $row);
    }
    fclose($FH);
};
```

Comment: you I put this like this :       foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    $row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val)."';
    fputcsv($FH, $row);
        }

Comment: and I'm getting syntax error for this line $row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val)."';

Comment: I checked my initial code when I print_r $callback  I'm getting all the values with leading zeros. and after downloading the file when I open it on notepad still the leading zeros there... issue comes when it opens in excel :( pls advice

Comment: I'm getting syntax error, unexpected end of file line 214, I've attached my code  to the question

Comment: I just tried  $row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val);    without putting last . " ' sections. then file get downloaded. but all cell walues has =" in front of values. may be because of I removed ." ' from code. but If I keep it I'm getting error . pls advice

Comment: @Tharuperera Oh my, I forgot a single-quote.  I updated my edit to `$row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val).'"';`

Comment: @Tharuperera No problem, glad I could help.